# Match against query not working - incorrect parameters

Tags: mysql, match-against

I have a table with articles and a table with categories. Each category has a number of keywords and I want to use those keywords to determine if an article belongs to a certain category.

I'm using the query below:

```
SELECT 
  path,
  title,
  description,
  keywords
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    path, 
    keywords, 
    (select title from article where id = 164016) as title,
    (select description from article where id = 164016) as description
  FROM 
    categories c 
) as x
WHERE 
  MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('my keywords' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

For some reason this query is not working because of incorrect paramaters with MATCH but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use [boolean fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) to enable exact matching on an expression. However, there are some limitations to such searches, as described by the documentation linked above:

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (") characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. **The full-text engine splits the phrase into words** and performs a search in the FULLTEXT index for the words. **Nonword characters need not be matched exactly**: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".
>
> If the phrase contains no words that are in the index, the result is
>   empty. The words might not be in the index because of a combination of
>   factors: if they do not exist in the text, are stopwords, or are
>   shorter than the minimum length of indexed words.

The above also means that if you have a stop word or a word shorter than the minimum length in the search expression, then MySQL will not return any matches.

```
SELECT path, keywords, MATCH (c.keywords) AGAINST ('"Here is some text"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
FROM categories c
WHERE MATCH (c.keywords) AGAINST ('"Here is some text"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If you want completely exact matches, then you cannot use fulltext search. You either need to use the `like` operator or the `=` operator.

UPDATE

1. `title` in this case is a calculated field which does not have a fulltext index.
2. `against()`

> takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html))

You have a field name in the `against()` function, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I think my objective is not going to work with my previous query. I think I should swap title and keywords so I made a new query, that is giving an error on the match against parameter. Maybe you have an idea what is wrong.

Comment: Is there some way how this could work? I changed the match against to title + description (description is fulltext) but it still does not work.

Comment: Since I have no idea what you want to achieve, I cannot help you in rewrting the query. I can only point you out the syntasx issues.

Comment: `IN BOOLEAN MODE` won't work if the engine is InnoDB

Comment: @Awaisfiaz that's incorrect. Boolean mode does work with innodb ever since fulltext index is supported by innodb (v5.6)